# Two urns with red and blue balls inside. What is the probability you picked a blue from Urn 1

Tags: probability

Urn 1 contains 7 red and 14 blue balls. Urn 2 contains 4 red and 8 blue balls. You select a ball from Urn 1 and move it to urn 2. Then from Urn 2 you pick a blue ball. What is the probability you picked a blue ball from Urn 1?

Can someone please check my solution?

**My solution:**

Let $A=${the event that a ball from Urn 1 is blue}

$B=${the event that ball from Urn 2 is blue}

$P(A)=\frac{14}{21}=\frac{2}{3}$

$P(A^c)=\frac{7}{21}=\frac{1}{3}$

If the selected ball from Urn 1 is blue then after the transfer there are 4 red balls and 9 blue balls in Urn 2. So:

$P(B|A)=\frac{9}{13}$

Similarly, if the selected ball from Urn 1 is red then after the transfer there are 5 red balls and 8 blue balls in Urn 2. So:

$P(B|A^c)=\frac{8}{13}$

Using LTP:

$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)$

$=\frac{9}{13}*\frac{2}{3}+\frac{8}{13}*\frac{1}{3}=\frac{26}{39}$

EDIT: Using Bayes' theorem:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)}$$

$$=\frac{(9/13)(2/3)}{26/39}=\frac{9}{13}$$

Comment: You've worked out the (unconditional) probability of the event $\ B\ $ correctly.   However, what you've been asked to calculate is the probability that $\ \color{red}{A}\ $ has occurred, presumably conditional on the fact that $\ B\ $ occurred, since you've been told that it did.  So what you should be  calculating is $\ P(A|B)\ $, for which you can use [Bayes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem).

Comment: ah yes, thank you so much! i just updated with baye's theorem, is my answer correct?

Comment: Your revised answer is indeed correct.